# Extract data in ArcGIS Online from map service hosted by ArcGIS for Server?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-online, map-service

I have only found scripting solutions and extensive workarounds.

Scenario:

- map services hosted on ArcServer
- looking to publish on organizational account on ArcGIS Online via REST

The most common operation our guys would like to do, is **export features as CSV, shp** etc... And I just cannot find any built-in solution in ArcGIS Online to do that! We´re currently using FlexViewer and people are used to that feature (at least the CSV export).

I found these Esri articles, e.g:

https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/share-maps/use-hosted-layers.htm

And a few workarounds, e.g.:

https://socalgis.org/2015/08/11/extracting-features-from-map-services/

Esri's article doesn´t work on map services. The workaround does work, but involves running a Python script.

Is there a native solution by Esri for this operation?

Comment: Provide an example URL of what you are interested in extracting from.

Comment: E.g. http://gis.npd.no/arcgis/rest/services/FactMaps/2_0/MapServer. Say I´d like to get feature with index 4 (Wellbores, exploration) as shape and CSV. How would I do that in ArcGIS Online? Thx

Comment: You can't extract data, using AGOL, from map services not hosted in AGOL. Even if they are hosted in AGOL, then the Feature Layer must have the option enabled to "Export Data".  If that option is not enabled, then you will not be able to extract the data. That being said, you can use Python to query out records in 1000 row chunks (using ObjectID), and then import that to a file geodatabase. But it sounds like you're not interested in that.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I thought so... It´s ridiculous though, even FlexViewer can export attribute tables as CSV and it seems there´s no free tool available to do it in Arc Online despite huge licensing costs, thanks ESRI... I never tried to publish toolboxes, should look into that, maybe I can script one to use for that purpose.

Comment: @alexGIS I think you should post your comment as an answer.